# Can we include 2 Mail() functions in 1 Page?

Tags: php, email, mysqli

I want to sent 2 different E-Mails to 2 different persons on 'Send Message' Button. I have few questions regarding this.

1. Is it possible to send Multiple Emails from same Page.
2. I have written the following code but its not sending Any Email and returning Error Message in return.

   > ```
   > <?php
   >
   > include 'connect.php';
   >
   > $subject = $_REQUEST['subject'] ; // Subject of your email
   > $personal_email= "abc@hotmail.com";
   >
   >
   > $message .= 'Name: ' . $_REQUEST['name'] . "<br>";
   > $message .= $_REQUEST['product_type']. "<br>";
   > $message .= $_REQUEST['message'];
   >
   >
   > $subject_to_sender= "Confirmation";
   > $message_to_sender = "Thanks for contacting us, Our representative will contact you shortly.";
   >
   >
   >
   > $name=            mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['name']);
   > $email=           mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['email']);
   > $message=     mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['message']);
   > $product_type=    mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['product_type']);
   > $address=     mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['address']);
   >
   > if($address== "")
   > {
   >   $address= "No Address is given.";
   > }
   >
   >
   > $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
   > $headers .= "From: " . $_REQUEST['email'] . "\r\n"; // Sender's E-mail
   > $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
   >
   >
   >
   > if (@mail($email, $subject_to_sender, $message_to_sender, $headers))
   > {
   >   mail($personal_email, $subject, $message, $headers);
   >   // Transfer the value 'sent' to ajax function for showing success message.
   >   echo 'sent';
   > ```

Comment: Why are you calling `mysql_real_escape_string`? You're not doing any MySQL queries.

Comment: You can call `mail()` as many times as you want.

Comment: remove mysql_real_escape_string()

Comment: Its printing the message written on else statement,

Comment: But there is no `else` clause in your above statement? Please remove the @ sign from the `mail()` statement so you'll see warnings returned from the call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your former question, I can say **Yes, its possible to use [mail()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function multiple times.**

For the later question, the opening bracket on last `if()` statement is not closed. Add `}` after `echo 'sent';` statement.